# TypeError: "set_postfix() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str" using Hyperopt

Tags: python, hyperopt

I try to run this simple example:

```
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp

best = fmin(
fn=lambda x: (x-1)**2,
space=hp.uniform('x', -2, 2),
algo=tpe.suggest,
max_evals=100)

print(best)
```

But this is what i get in the console:

```
...\WinPython\python-3.6.5.amd64\Lib\site-packages\tqdm\_tqdm.py", line 792, in __init__
self.set_postfix(refresh=False, **postfix)
```

TypeError: set_postfix() argument after ** must be a mapping, not str

Why?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is helpful. I was facing the same error when i try to tune the randomforest classifier model. I changed my objective function arguments from **params to *args and it fixed the error :)

Comment: **This is an answer** - it suggests to use `*args` instead of `**params`